# how to give a _rec_name as a combination of two field in odoo 10?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

how to display a code(or a number) + name when selecting in many2one field?

or

how to give a _rec_name as a combination of two field?

or

how to combine two fields on saving.

for example:There are two fields like name and employee id. After filling up those fields and saving. On opening the record, the _rec_name should display as name[employee id].

Comment: Do you have an actual problem? An example of what output you are expecting for what input and the code you have tried to achieve that? A [minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What i want is to display a name field and an integer field on the actwindow while opening a record. for example. if i create an employee record in the name of john and his id is 002. While saving it should save a john[002]. I can't upload pics bcuz i am new here. Kindly help me to solve this @SarahPhillips. Thank You

Comment: No pics please, share the actual code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite the _name_get method in your class:

```
    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        result = []
        for s in self:
            name = s.field1+ ' ' + s.field2
            result.append((s.id, name))
        return result
```

I hope this help you.